# Casting contract to interface

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I have a function that expects interfaceA and a hardhat instance of class B that implements interfaceA, how can I call that function, seems like just sending B doesn't work and also casting to address doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see where your problem is, consider this example :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

interface A {  
    function interfaceFunction() external returns(uint256);
}

contract B is A {
    function interfaceFunction() public virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return 1;
    }
}

contract C {
    B implementsInterface;
    
    constructor(B _implementsInterface) {
        implementsInterface = _implementsInterface;
    }
    
    function asParameter(A _interface) public returns (uint256) {
        return _interface.interfaceFunction();
    }
    
    function asProperty() public returns (uint256) {
        return asParameter(implementsInterface);
    }
}
```

Where A is your interface, B is your contract implementing interface A and C is just a contract to call the interface functions through B.

You can either call C.asParameter giving the address of B or C.asProperty. Both work perfectly even though C.asParameter expects an adress of type A.

There shouldn't be any issue as A is a supertype of B, so substituting type A to type B is perfectly valid as long as you don't intend to use any specific logic from B that is not declared in A.